# Why font-family sporadically adds 1px gap between buttons?

Tags: html, css, fonts

**Please read the question carefully. It's not the same as the one about [How to remove the space between inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/247243).**

Consider the following HTML:

```css
body {
  /* font-family: Arial; */
}

.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="my-class">Hello</button>
  <button class="my-class">Stack</button>
  <button class="my-class">Overflow</button>
</div>
```

Which produces:

[image: screenshot 1]

But, if I add:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

it results in a 1px space between the second and third buttons:

[image: screenshot 2]

**The question is:** Why adding `font-family` to the `body` affects the space between the buttons?

Comment: try this: delete spaces between close and open button tags -> </button><button>. sometimes it's spaces in html that cause this.

Comment: the above answers are correct, the reason behind that is each and every browser has its own setting for rendering a page, better globally set font-size (ex: body{font-size:12px;}) may avoid these kind of issues!!

Comment: The `<kbd>` element is used to denote user input, **not** hyperlinks. Please don't decorate your hyperlinks with these.

Comment: @Aru That's interesting! Could you elaborate on that or provide some references?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko, check these articles http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/ and http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/

Comment: I'm getting some mixed results from your demo. At first it has messed up spacing, after messing around with things for a while it seems to fix itself. Weird

Comment: On chrome 39 beta, there is no difference if I add the font-family.

Comment: Most importantly is to know, what browsers/devices/platforms can you reproduce the issue? Your [demo](http://jsbin.com/bulowuvavepa/1/edit) works just the same with or without `font-family` in Firefox 33.0, Chrome 38.0.2125.104 m, Opera 12.17 [1863], Opera 25.0.1614.50 and Safari 5.1.7(7534.57.2) (all Windows)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It happens because each font has different width, even for the space character. You already know about the whitespace issues with inline-blocks. So, when you set Arial, those whitespaces change their width slightly from the browser's default font (or any other font with different width), which is Times New Roman in my case.

See how drastic the change is when you set the monospace font.

Now, **why** it happens between the 2nd and the 3rd box and not the 1st and the 2nd one? I'm pretty sure it comes down to rounding pixel values based on the width of the words entered, seems like there is a pseudo sub-pixel rendering present in the background, yet the decimal values get rounded in the final render process. See what happens if you use Arial and print Hell Stack Overflow instead of Hello Stack Overflow - the gaps look the same. So, it's just an undesired coincidence.

Another point that proves this is a rounding issue is the change in the gaps across various page zoom levels. It's fairly common to get these pixel mismatches in the layout when dealing with decimals in HTML. Zooming adds another dividing/multiplication stage, which changes the core values even further, resulting in completely unpredictable behaviour in the final layout.

Comment: Btw. I doubt you'll ever get `an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources` because it's a combination of answers about 3-4 different topics (some of which could differ from browser to browser quite possibly), so summing those into one solid answer would look iffy, at best.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't like **any** of the other answers so I didn't upvote any of them because they are all too focused on what OP **clearly** stated we should not talk about: the whitespace issue with inline-blocks and how to fix it. And @dippas, about 90% of your answer is about that as well, so I can see why you could get downvoted.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the rounding off issue as a possible cuplrit.

Answer (score 11):

It's because you're displaying the buttons as `inline-block` elements and when you have inline elements whitespace is significant and is rendered in the same way that spaces between words is rendered.

i.e inline-block makes whitespace significant, so spaces in the source between `inline-block` elements will be rendered.

For example: You could center the `inline-block` elements just by adding `text-align: center;` the same way is used to center the text in its parent block element. - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ooLj0zb/)**

> Why adding font-family to the body affects the space between the buttons?

Different fonts can have different spacing between words, If you compare `font-family: monospace;` with `font-family: sans-serif;` then you will see the `monospace` fonts have more space between words than `sans-serif` fonts and the `inline-block` elements is also rendered in the same way and have the spacing between elements.

- [Monospace DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duvxyym7/)
- [Sans-serif DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4o7s4t7z/)

The best way to remove the space between `inline-block` elements is adding the `font-size: 0;` to the parent element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tnaoo7dL/)**

```css
div {
  font-size: 0;
}
.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="my-class">Hello</button>
    <button class="my-class">Stack</button>
    <button class="my-class">Overflow</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not explain why the spacing is inconsistent (which is the actual question).

Comment: The spacing between inline-block elements is equivalent to the width of one character on the inherited font, so I tried to compare two fonts that have different spacing between words by showing inline-block rendered the same way and have different spacing between elements as per the font-family, so margin -4px doesn't help to remove the spacing between inline-block elements. Please correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: An important bit in the question is that `-4px` covers the gap between first and second button but not between second and third. 
Inherited font and size are the same but spacing is inconsistent.

Answer (score 8):

**The answer assumes that [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371554(v=vs.85).aspx) is enabled. You will not notice the specified symptoms and fractional widths otherwise. It is also assumed that default serif and sans-serif fonts are Times New Roman and Arial.**

---

Whoever said that the space character is 4px wide is mistaken:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".demo").each(function() {
        var width = $("span", this).width();
        $("ins", this).text("total width: " + width + "px, " + (width / 10) + "px per space)");
    });
});
```

```css
.demo {
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #EEE;
}
.demo-1 {
    font: 16px/1 sans-serif;
}
.demo-2 {
    font: 16px/1 serif;
}
.demo-3 {
    font: 16px/1 monospace;
}
.demo span {
    float: left;
    background: #CF0;
}
.demo ins {
    float: right;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<p>The green blocks contain 10 spaces:</p>
<p class="demo demo-1"><span>          </span><ins></ins></p>
<p class="demo demo-2"><span>          </span><ins></ins></p>
<p class="demo demo-3"><span>          </span><ins></ins></p>
```

Note that:

1. For a given size the character width depends on font family.
2. The character width does not necessarily have to be a whole number. Serif font gives you a nice whole number (4px), but Sans-serif font gives you fractional number (4.4px).

You could get different results in different browsers depending on how they handle fractional gaps between two blocks (e.g. 4.4px for 16px Arial). CSS specs are silent about this.

In Chrome with DirectWrite enabled, spaces are rendered as 4px and 5px alternately due to rounding off. This explains why there is no gap between first and second button and 1px gap between second and third. Try adding more buttons in your original example and notice how the pattern repeats ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ooLj0zb/5/show/)).

Using `margin-left: -4.4px` seems to work but it is not *guaranteed* to work. [**Consider going back to the alternate solutions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Comment: Those alternate solutions you mentioned (link) are exactly in my answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

## PROBLEM:

this happens because the `display` is set to `inline-block`.

### inline-block is:

> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with
>   surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much
>   like a replaced element would)

**»» see more about display property here:  [DISPLAY INFO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**

## SOLUTION(S):

- Remove the spaces
- Negative margin
- Skip the closing tag
- Set the font size to zero
- Just float them instead
- Just use flexbox instead

For more details on each solution check 


## Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements

*my preferred solutions from above is*

> Set the font size to zero

therefore is a **snippet** with your code and my preferred solution:

```css
div {
 font-size:0;
}

.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font:normal 12px Arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="my-class">Hello</button>
  <button class="my-class">Stack</button>
  <button class="my-class">Overflow</button>
</div>
```

Plus, here is a snippet with your **EXACT CODE** only changing the `font-family` from `body` to the elements that have `display:inline-block`, and achieving the same output as my **FIRST SNIPPET**

```css
.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;  /* Remove the space between inline elements */
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="my-class">Hello</button>
  <button class="my-class">Stack</button>
  <button class="my-class">Overflow</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

OP's question:

> *Why adding font-family to the body affects the space between the*
>   *buttons?*

in **web typography** there are:

- **Sans-serif**

  Fonts that do not have decorative markings, or serifs, on their letters. These fonts are often considered easier to read on screens.
- **Serif**

  Fonts that have decorative markings, or serifs, present on their characters.
- **Monospace**

  Fonts in which all characters are equally wide.
- **Cursive**

  Fonts that resemble cursive writing. These fonts may have a decorative appearance, but they can be difficult to read at small sizes, so they are generally used sparingly.
- **Fantasy**

  Fonts that may contain symbols or other decorative properties, but still represent the specified character.

Since **Arial** is a **sans-serif** font, therefore a *non-fixed width font* ( like monospace ), when applied to `body` with child elements displaying `inline-block`(without fix for the gaps) it will create space between the child elements.

Although if you apply the `font-family` to the child elements, like **I DID** in my **2ND SNIPPET** it doesn't happen anymore.

---

one comment of an article:

> *The gap between inline elements is, as you suggest, a space character.*
>   *The width depends on the font (family, variant, etc.) and approximates*
>   *to .25em*

you can check it [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/#comment-364108)

the full article is below

## ARTICLE

Comment: The question is why adding `font-family` to `body` affects the space between the buttons? You didn't answer the question.

Comment: I gave you 2 snippets, both with same result, one with a fix for inline-block, another one with your CODE adding  font-family:Arial, So I don't see how font-family:Arial is influencing your outcome.. in your code sample you have a typo tough , you wrote body {font-family: Arial;;} instead body {font-family: Arial;}.

Answer (score 4):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/mebisopehibe/1/edit)

The problem is that there are *hidden* spaces (*a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear*) between tags. Minimize the HTML or comment the spaces out and everything will work correct:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button class="my-class">Hello</button><!--
    --><button class="my-class">Stack</button><!--
    --><button class="my-class">Overflow</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why adding `font-family` to `body` causing the space between the buttons.

Comment: However this solves the problem and highlights the issue (spaces).

Comment: @MishaMoroshko, that is because the buttons have likely a different spacing (e.g. a tab instead of four spaces on the first button), and their width is different depending on what font has been selected. That's why, if you remove the spaces, font is no longer an issue. You should be able to check by using a monospaced font and `white-space: pre` mode.

Answer (score 4):

Check the demo and use this CSS. If you have not satisfied, just change the font size. It will get fixed.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  
}

.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
  background-color: ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="my-class">Hello</button>
    <button class="my-class">Stack</button>
    <button class="my-class">Overflow</button>
  </div>
```

See also [JSfiddle](http://jsbin.com/wexajuviha/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use

```
float:left
```

or

```
float:right
```

instead

```
 display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use the below css for this: 

.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right:-1px;
}
```

Comment: It's taking margin from right. So please use margin-right:-1px or 0px;

Comment: I have checked it through the Playground Here Code and it's working.

Comment: body {
  font-family: Arial;
  //font-size: 13px;
}

.my-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -1px 0 -4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}